# How i can get a value from JSON string

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm trying to get values for the `"response"` object from the JSON below.
I have a problem because I don't know how to get the data from JSON. I'm new in this.

```
{
    "error": false,
    "response": {
        "id": 6818,
        "name": "Krashnz",
        "avatar": "https:\/\/static.truckersmp.com\/avatarsN\/6818.1538179228.png",
        "smallAvatar": "https:\/\/static.truckersmp.com\/avatarsN\/small\/6818.1538179228.png",
        "joinDate": "2014-11-14 01:33:03",
        "steamID64": 76561198046080290,
        "steamID": "76561198046080290",
        "groupName": "Developer",
        "groupID": 2,
        "banned": false,
        "bannedUntil": null,
        "displayBans": false,
        "permissions": {
            "isGameAdmin": true,
            "showDetailedOnWebMaps": false
        },
        "vtc": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "TruckersMP Developers",
            "tag": "TMP-DEV",
            "inVTC": true,
            "memberID": 1579
        }
    }
}
```

How i can do it? Im working in C#

Comment: Hi, could you please share the code you use for extracting the response from the above JSON ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a tool like [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to convert the json to C# classes.  Then use Newtonsoft.Json nuget package to deserialize the json into your class.

Create the classes below.  Then you can deserialise like:

```
var json = // your json string
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
var response = root.Response;


// classes below
public class Permissions
{
    public bool isGameAdmin { get; set; }
    public bool showDetailedOnWebMaps { get; set; }
}

public class Vtc
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public bool inVTC { get; set; }
    public int memberID { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string avatar { get; set; }
    public string smallAvatar { get; set; }
    public string joinDate { get; set; }
    public long steamID64 { get; set; }
    public string steamID { get; set; }
    public string groupName { get; set; }
    public int groupID { get; set; }
    public bool banned { get; set; }
    public object bannedUntil { get; set; }
    public bool displayBans { get; set; }
    public Permissions permissions { get; set; }
    public Vtc vtc { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool error { get; set; }
    public Response response { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help!